# Handle PHP longint on 32bit system

Tags: php, 64-bit, integer, 32-bit

I'm using a 32bit system and I have to handle longint. Is there any way to handle longint (64bit integer) in PHP on 32bit system? (I cannot use (int) convertion)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [GMP library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php) or [BCmath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) which are usually installed with PHP.

Check out the [Working with large numbers in PHP](http://Working%20with%20large%20numbers%20in%20PHP.) thread for more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php

> Thank you for your answer, but if I want to bind a longint to a query using prepare statement in most of the db connection provider, is there any way to do it?

I don't know which particular interface you are using, but you can probably convert the GMP (or whatever you use) integer into a numeric string. Then bind that numeric string and it should work.